# unable to fetch api using the redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have watched a tutorial to know how redux toolkit work after watching that he uses some online api providing service now when i am using it i need to customize it for my use so i have did change the name and the urls

here is my store.js

```
    import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {setupListeners} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { postApi } from './actions/productAction'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        [postApi.reducerPath]:postApi.reducer
    },

    // middleware:(getDefaultMiddleware)=>getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postApi.middleware),

    // middleware is also created for us, which will allow us to take advantage of caching, invalidation, polling, and the other features of RTK Query.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postApi.middleware),
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

Here i have the action file which is actually taking the action updating state

```
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const postApi = createApi({
    reducerPath:'postApi',//this is unique path which will tell the broweser where it need to store the cookie data
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl:'',
    }),
    endpoints:(builder)=>({
        getAllPost: builder.query({
            query:()=>({
                url:'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/products',
                method:'GET'
            })
        }),
        getPostById: builder.query({
            query: (id) =>({
                url:`posts/${id}`,
                method:'GET'
            })
        })
    })
})

export const {useGetAllPostQuery,useGetPostByIdQuery} = postApi
```

The place where i am calling this function is

```
import React from 'react'
import {useGetAllPostQuery} from '../../actions/productAction'
// import Card from '../../components/Card';

const HomePage = () => {

  console.log(useGetAllPostQuery())
  const responseInfo = useGetAllPostQuery()

  console.log("the response i am getting is",responseInfo)
  
  return (
    <>
    <h1>Hello worls</h1>
    
  </>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

my console where i am getting i dont why this error is coming
the request is rejcted at the same time my post man works on that
[image]

The error expanded image

[image]

The actual issue is

[image]

Comment: Can you also add the expandable error object image and your base URL is empty

Comment: i have updated the question kindly check

Answer (score 1):

looks like it is not getting the Url Try adding your base URL like this

```
export const postApi = createApi({
    reducerPath:'postApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl:'http://localhost:5000/',  //added your base url
    }),
    endpoints:(builder)=>({
        getAllPost: builder.query({
            query:()=>({
                url:'api/v1/products' // this should take only one argument
            })
        }),
        getPostById: builder.query({
            query: (id) =>({
                url:`posts/${id}`  // this should take only one argument
            })
        })
    })
})
```

For more Details, you can refer to here [rtk query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries)

Comment: Well i have first try this only because i am getting the error then i try that

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: the same which i am getting now i also feel that there might something wrong with the url so i think to make it blank and add all in one line that also give the same error

Comment: i was able to fetch data with axios

Comment: remove the method get from both the builder query ` method:'GET'`  and try again but keep the base URL it is standard way to do it

Comment: updated the answer you can check

Comment: i tried still not working i think the issue might be in the my json response it response 3 json objects

Comment: also one issue i want to highlight the api is getting called 4  times i call once

Comment: I have finally understand the final issue its cors issue just updated check

Answer (score 1):

Bro, I watch that tutorial too, it is old.
Here is the correct way to fetch. Please let me know if this answer help you. And also you auto complete to import. You're not importing from the right place if you follow that tutorial.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react'
import {useGetAllPostQuery} from '../../actions/productAction'
// import Card from '../../components/Card';

const HomePage = () => {

  console.log(useGetAllPostQuery())
  //You can also desctructure it like this {data:responseInfo}, you must not directly change the value. 
  const {data} = useGetAllPostQuery()


  
  return (
    <>
    //Then you check if data exist first because the initial value is empty. you can also check like this <div>{data?.map((my data)=> <>...</>))}</div>
    
    <div>{data && data.map((mydata, i)=> (
    //You can tag on what you want to display. if you want to display names, then you can say madata.name
    <p key={i}>{mydata}</p>
    ))}</div>
    
  </>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

To solve cors errors, try this:

Create vercel.json under the root folder.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" }, // Change this to specific domain for better security
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Go to /api/index.js file.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;

  // This will allow OPTIONS request
  if (method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.status(200).send("ok");
  }
};
```

Comment: i have followed the tutorial but now i want to do my work not what he do so i have my code base

Comment: Were you able to get the data?

Comment: yes i was able to fetch data if i baseUrl="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/" but when i change it to localhost it does not work

Comment: You should put slash '/' at the back of localhost:3000/

Comment: have you just readed see i have uploaded the actual issue

Comment: where in which file you see localhost 3000

Comment: I will edit the answer for you now

Comment: Dear my issue is solved i appritiate your effort my issue was in cors

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer?

Comment: yes i am writing the answer just wait

Answer (score 0):

I was not looking console properly the main issue was that the backend was not allowing me to query the api which is kind strange i have not find this using axios means i not need to use cors to access api using axios but if you are doing it using redux  tool kit then you need to use cors

```
npm install cors
```

then add these line in your main backend file

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```